# How can I add a CRUD system into wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, integration, crud

I've searched high and low into finding a way to integrate a CRUD (create, read, update, delete) table system database into WordPress.

Users would essentially login and then be redirected to the front end which would show the data table / grid and be able to add records / edit / delete as necessary.

Would have to be able to export the data via xls, pdf, csv, etc...
Would also need the capability to also integrate a calendar somehow with the records.

For example if I create a record full of patients, and after the column for name I have a column for status and if it is activated then the calendar would pick it up.

I'm kind of talking out of my head here, I know; I'm just trying to conceptualize what I am trying to accomplish.

I'm a WordPress vet and I know that its vastly flexible but what I'm asking for is a bit of a niche demand.

Comment: If there's no existing plugin, you'll probably have to roll your own #statingtheobvious. Have you looked for one? If there isn't one, I'm not sure Wordpress is ideal for this sort of thing. You might want to look at one of the PHP ORMs (like Cake PHP or Zend)

Comment: The main reason for using it is because there are other facets that make it convenient such as login and login privileges as well as being able to customize it so heavily up till a certain point. The real task at hand is finding something that I can use or integrate somehow , even if it's an include into a wordpress page via php

Comment: This "question" is way too broad and open-ended. It's highly unlikely you will find a plugin or other "prebuilt" solution that will meet all your requirements. You will, most likely, have to roll up your sleeves and build something yourself.

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to what you need.
But if I have any idea whatsoever - you would have to roll your own plugin. Know much about plugin development?